# Run/Debug CURRENT file in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

I have a lot of scripts I want to run / debug from Webstorm, but for each I have to go thru the process of "Run > Edit Configurations" and add a new configuration mapped to each file.

Is there a variable / shortcut to tell WebStorm to run / debug currently opened file?
Something like `${opened-file}` would be great to have a Run Configuration "template".

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such variable, unfortunately. Have you tried right click and choose Run/Debug from there? (temp config will be created)

Comment: Nope I don't find any such menu item either from the project files panel, or the tabs, or the app menu... Snif

Comment: But it's there: Editor context menu: http://s17.postimg.org/jjo1bo9z3/screen01.png ; Project View context menu: http://s12.postimg.org/7441lxiv1/screen02.png

Answer (score 5):

`Application parameters` has a macros support (plus icon in the field). You need to use `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$` macros.

This example runs `node /node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.local.conf.js --spec foo.js`. `foo.js` is `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$`

[image]

Comment: I have `~/tmp` as my working directory and am using `$FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$` for the file param, but it gives an error trying to run it: `Cannot find module '/Users/ken/tmp'`. Makes no sense to me, why it's trying to load my working dir as a module? Luckily @Pnar's answer below works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do 'Run context configuration' to execute the current open file. The default shortcut should be control+shift+R on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is right clicking the file, then choosing `Run <filename>`. This will run the current file using the defaults from the Run Configuration.

Comment: This works for .js files but I cant get it to work for .ts files :/

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the pain you're feeling. I have a similar desire. However, there may be a way to accomplish what you're trying to do without it.

I'm using Webstorm + Jasmine for node development. Here are the steps I followed to get a working TDD setup:

1. install jasmine (Preferences->Frameworks & Frameworks->Node or just from cmd line).
2. setup test directory (eg, src/test or src/spec)
3. setup jasmine.json config file in root of test directory. Mine looks like this:

```js
{
  "spec_dir": "src/test",
  "spec_files": [ "**/*[sS]pec.js" ]
}
```

4. write a test file:

```js
describe('HelloWorld', function () {
  const HelloWorld = require('../HelloWorld');

  describe('#greeting', function() {
    it('should be friendly', function() {
      expect(new HelloWorld().greeting()).toEqual("Hello, World");
    });
  });
});
```

5. setup run/debug config: *default* node runner with options:

   - pick your node interpreter
   - node argument:  node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js
   - environment variable: JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH = src/test/jasmine.json (set in step 4 above)

     This produces an entry in the .idea/workspace.xml file like this:

```xml
<configuration default="true" type="NodeJSConfigurationType" factoryName="Node.js" path-to-node="project" node-parameters="node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js" working-dir="$PROJECT_DIR$">
   <envs>
     <env name="JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH" value="src/test/jasmine.json" />
   </envs>
</configuration>
```

6. Open any test file, and use the keyboard shortcut ctrl+shift+R. This will make a new temporary run config from the default node run config, but with the current test file filled in for the `Javascript file` option.

I've created a pretty fluid workflow with this setup. Considering that ctrl+R will re-run the last run config, you can be writing the test, use ctrl+shift+R to run it, then start writing the code, and use ctrl+R to re-run that same test file.

Comment: BTW... at this point, with Jest handling built in, I'm usually just defaulting to jest instead of jasmine for TDD of client code under node.